# Android dispatchKeyEvent not called when Dialog fragment is show

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

when my dialog fragment is `hide`, `dispatchKeyEvent` worked fine

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {

    Toast.makeText(FragmentPlayer.this, "test: called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);

}
```

but when my dialog fragment is `show`, `dispatchKeyEvent` not called

```
MyDialogFragment mFragment = new MyDialogFragment();
mFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "MyDialog");
```

why?

Comment: I have the same problem, Did you figure that out?

Comment: @Kingcesc i found issue and fixed it

Comment: @grizzly What is the issue? I have similar problem.

Comment: @Yeung. you must use `... extends Dialog`. not use `dialog fragment`. Simple `Dialog` class `dispatchKeyEvent` fix and is ok. when dialog fragment is show, dispatchKeyEvent not working. so you should use `Dialog` class

Answer (score 9):

No need to change your `DialogFragment` code to `Dialog`, you can do something like this (In case still needed). Using `OnKeyListener` will solve your problem.

```
public class BaseDialogFragment extends AppCompatDialogFragment {

  @Override
  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    getDialog().setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            /* Your logic, you get the KeyEvent*/
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: hi, How to add setOnKeyListener in a fragment. I am trying to read an RFID HID device from a fragment. Tried adding a listener in the root view but not working

Comment: @AravindOR You will need to listen key event on the fragment's activity. override dispatchKeyEvent() and check if the current fragment is the required one

Answer (score 0):

Inside your **DialogFragment** for your keys` actions, you can use:

```
getDialog().dispatchKeyEvent(event);
```

instead of

```
getActivity().dispatchKeyEvent(event);
```